# Reading in from file to 2 arrays

Tags: c++

Here is my problem, I'm trying to read in data from a file `"beginningbalance.dat"`, containing the following:

```
111
100.00
200.00
50.00
222
200.00
300.00
100.00
```

What I want to do is read in `111` for `customer_number[0]` and `222` for `customer_number[1]`. For `new_balance[0]`, I want to add the values of the 3 numbers under `111` and `new_balance[1]` the numbers under `222`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  double val1, val2, val3, sum;
  int customer_number[2];//Array for holding customer number from file.
  double new_balance[2];//Array for holding added values from file.

  ifstream beginning_balance;
  beginning_balance.open("beginningbalance.dat");



  while(beginning_balance)
    {
        beginning_balance >> customer_number[count];
        beginning_balance >> val1;
        beginning_balance >> val2;
        beginning_balance >> val3;

        sum = val1+val2+val3;

        new_balance[count] = sum; //Supposed to read in customer id number then 3 values from files, then starts itself over and reads a new customer number for the new array element.
        count++;                   //
    }

  cout<<val1<<" "<<val2<<" "<<val3<<"\n\n";//Testing values being read in

  cout<<"Customer Number #"<<customer_number[0]<<endl;//Should read Customer Number # 111
  cout<<"New Balance $"<<new_balance[0]<<endl;
  cout<<"Customer Number #"<<customer_number[1]<<endl;//Should read Customer Number # 222
  cout<<"New Balance $"<<new_balance[1]<<endl;



  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

My output is

```
100  -858993460 -858993460

Customer Number #111
New Balance $-1.71799e+009
Customer Number #0
New Balance $5.48413e-322
Press any key to continue...
```

{I had my `val1,val2,val3`,and `sum` set to `int` when it should have been something to allow floating point numbers, I also only allowed 1 element for each array.}

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to look and see what is happening while the program is executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the whole bug, but it's at least part of it:

```
int customer_number[1];//Array for holding customer number from file.
double new_balance[1];//Array for holding added values from file.
```

You've declared these `[1]` which means "1 element with index 0". If you want indexes 0 and 1 then you should use `[2]`. By overrunning your array bounds you're corrupting the memory of other variables nearby, which probably explains the bad balance values. (But maybe not the bad val2 and val3 values.)

However since your code allows you to read in an arbitrary number of data sets you should consider using an stl::vector or similar for these, or probably an stl::vector of a structure / class that contains the customer number and balance as a single object.

Comment: You're right about changing the array size that was just a lapse in memory confusing it with number names. But that doesn't fix it reading in the correct values and I'm not onto vectors yet.

Answer (score 1):

While array indexing start with zero, array definition does not. One of your problems is that you only define the arrays `customer_number` and `new_balance` to contain one entry each, and then you put in two values at different index. This will overwrite memory, and may cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

An array declared as

```
int customer_number[1];
```

has only 1 element, of index 0. Very probably, you want to have it more than one element. Try to replace `[1]` with e.g. `|8]` (and be careful that each index accessing it is between 0 and 7 = 8-1)

Also, compile your code with all warnings enabled, and debugging information. On Linux, that means `g++ -Wall -g` and improve your code till you got no warnings at all.

Learn how to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux), in particular how to run step by step a program under the debugger and how to inspect variables.

Answer (score 1):

Also note you should declare

```
float val1, val2, val3, sum;
```

or

```
double val1, val2, val3, sum;
```

if you want to accumulate floating point values for the data amounts

Comment: Great! You should tick Bogatyr's answer then as the one that solved it for you - thanks.